# Extract/download SharePoint Online Search reports (Top Queries)

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, reports, online

Is there any way to extract/download the Excel sheet report "Top Queries by Day"?
We would like to use it to display top 10 searched queries throughout the week...

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you are SharePoint Administrator. Open the SPO Admin center and navigate to Classic Feature from left menu. Now click on Open button for Search. This will take you the Search Administration page, now from the menu click on 'View usage report', and you get the option to export data to excel file for top 10 queries.

Admin center URL: https://-admin.sharepoint.com

Direct URL to Usage Report page: https://-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/reporting.aspx?Category=AnalyticsSearch

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the report manually, just click on the "Top Queries by Day" and the excel file will be downloaded automatically.

You can find the search reports for each site collection via Site Settings > Popularity and Search Reports and those for the tenant via Classic SharePoint admin center > search > View Usage Reports.

Reference:

[View search usage reports.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/view-search-usage-reports)